# EditText calls onFocusChanged three times instead of once

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, focusable

I have to do a `ListView` that contains on each item an `EditText`. If the EditText receives focus, I have to display a dialog - the condition is strictly for when the EditText receives focus and not when is pressed because it can be selected even if it is not pressed...

To do this I use a focus listener on the `EditText` but the `onFocusChanged` gets called three times instead on only one when the user presses the `EditText`, this means the dialog gets called twice...

This is the sequence of the calls:

- **Has focus**
- **Lost focus**
- **Has focus**

I don't have any other special handling of the `ListView` or `EditText` .. so it should be from the system somehow, maybe because I am using the EditText on the ListView which is a focusable `View` too..

Does anyone have any ideas why is this happening and how can I "fix" this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: EditText inside a ListView has always been a lethal combination. Try inflating a LinearLayout instead, the issue might get resolved.

Comment: @ShishirShetty Can you be more specific ? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26562879/676612 something like this.