# How to configure an inner-layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout defined in `xml`, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- add views here -->            

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am inflating it inside my activity, but the `RelativeLayout` needs to have `TextViews` depending on data from the application. How could I possibly extend it and add different views in it?

---

Note: this is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697405/how-to-correctly-extend-linearlayout-to-create-a-custom-view) because I am trying to figure out how to extend an **inner**-layout without using a class for the content I want to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create the Textviews in Code. Then add them to your Layout:

```
RelativeLayout innerLayout= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.inner_layout);

TextView textView = new TextView(this);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

textView.setLayoutParams(p);

innerLayout.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id=@+id/inner_layout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <!-- add views here -->            

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/app"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
 RelativeLayout relativelayout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.inner_layout);
 relativelayout.addview(//Add view here(one will be allowed));
```

if you ordering your views in RelativeLayout use rules. Better to use LinearLayout.