# CustomView doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a custom View class that represents a domino, following the solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697405/how-to-correctly-extend-linearlayout-to-create-a-custom-view) answer. No error, the app runs but nothing shows up. Since it's very similiar to the referenced question in the link, i guess it's just a small problem, but i don't find the fault in the code.

The Domino.java:

```
package com.example.android.dominoneu;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class Domino extends LinearLayout {

    public Domino(Context context){

        super(context);
    }
}
```

the domino.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.android.dominoneu.Domino xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:Domino="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

</com.example.android.dominoneu.Domino>
```

In MainActivity, it's added:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout board;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        board = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.board);
        board.addView(new Domino(this));

    }
}
```

Comment: domino.xml is not activity_main.xml Maybe this is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong, but you're only extending the LinearLayout (is that what you want?).
If you want to every time you reference your Domino View, shows a custom layout, you need to inflate your layout in your constructor. See the following code from the other question:

```
public Card(Context context) {
    super(context);

    View view =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.card, null);

    this.addView(view);

}
```

It's not necessary need to use the "this.addView(view);" like the other question, if you use the following inflate method.

```
LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, this, true);
```

So, your domino.xml will be the following (example):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LEFT"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RIGHT"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Your Domino Class (example):

```
public class Domino extends LinearLayout {

    public Domino (Context context) {
        super(context);

        View view =  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.domino, this, true);

        // Customize your view, E.g.:
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText("Foobar domino");
    }

    // add the following if you like to reference Domino View in a Layout
    public Domino(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.domino, this, true);

        // Customize your view, E.g.:
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText("Foobar domino");
    }
}
```

And your Activity will be the same (if you're trying to add Domino Views dynamically) or reference your Domino View in your MainActivity Layout.

Good coding.

Comment: You're right, that's what i want....I confused the issue (add view dynamically vs use it as xml)

Answer (score 1):

Add `Domino(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` constructor to your view. This is used by XML to create an instance of your view.

And there is no need to add it manually with `addView` if you use xml

Answer (score 1):

You should create this constructor

```
public Domino(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
/*do here all what you want with custom view*/
}
```

Comment: Only 1 constructor with Context and AttributeSet is enough

Answer (score 1):

You have to add all the 4 super constructors like this.

```
public class Domino extends LinearLayout {
    public Domino(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Domino(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Domino(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public Domino(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Only 1 constructor with Context and AttributeSet is enough