# android :Removing random space between dynamically generated ImageView and TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am currently working at developing an app that requires a dynamically generated `GridView`. In the layout added to the `GridView` through an adapter I have a LinearLayout that takes information from an `ArrayList` and then it should display an `ImageView` followed by a `TextView`. I have done that programmatically, but some random space appears between the two of them.

I have tried removing the padding, removing the margin, setting the adjustViewBounds of the image to true and also removing the inner padding of the TextView and none of these things work.

Here is the .xml file containing the LinearLayout to be populated:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_text_black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/horizontal_white_line"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        **android:id="@+id/orderLayout"**
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/separator"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="40dp">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/separator"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@mipmap/effects"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/moodText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/smallText"
            android:padding="0dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tastesText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/smallText"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:padding="0dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tastesText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            style="@style/smallText"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:padding="0dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code that generates the image-text pairs:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                int currentPos = orderSize - i;
                if(currentPos >= 0){
                    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(v.getContext());
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams containerParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    container.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                    container.setLayoutParams(containerParams);

                    ImageView img = new ImageView(v.getContext());
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    imgParams.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
                    img.setLayoutParams(imgParams);
                    img.setPadding(0,0,0,0);


                    if(order.get(currentPos).delivered){
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_circle);
                    }
                    else{
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_circle);
                    }

                    TextView txt = new TextView(v.getContext());
                    txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    txt.setText(order.get(currentPos).orderItem);
                    txt.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

                    container.addView(img);
                    container.addView(txt);
                    ll.addView(container);

                }
```

And here is the result:

[image: Result]

The red rectangle indicates the extra space.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Consider using ListView or RecyclerView instead of LinearLayout. Then why you are creating programmatically your view? Starting from an xml layout you can see the result first

Comment: I am basically trying to present the situation of multiple tables in a bar. Each table is on of these views. Using a ListView would not work as I am already inside an adapter, so I think it would be quite troublesome to create a second adapter for the ListView.

Comment: Ok, but why are you adding this view programmatically? You can inflate a layout to start from a tested resource

Comment: I am adding it programmatically because the number of tables can vary anywhere between say 5 and 50, so I need to account for that.

Comment: I'm talking about image-text pairs creation. Adding programmatically is correct, but instead of new LinearLayout, new ImageView, etc you can use LayoutInflater to inflate directly an xml layout file. tell me if you need an example

Comment: @firegloves could you please give me an example of how to achieve that? I am a bit unsure of how it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to create your line item view (green ball and drink name) in an xml layout, checking that all is working fine on a single line.

Then you can change your for cycle as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    int currentPos = orderSize - i;
    if(currentPos >= 0){

        // inflate a new instance of view starting from an xml file
        View tableLineView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.table_line, null);

        // Image view
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)tableLineView.findViewById(R.id.ball);
        if(order.get(currentPos).delivered){
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_circle);
        } else{
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow_circle);
        }

        // TextView
        TextView tv = (TextView)tableLineView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText(order.get(currentPos).orderItem);

        // add to LinearLayout
        ll.addView(tableLineView);
    }
}
```

I can't test it now, if you find problems ask me.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118943/how-to-inflate-android-view-in-linearlayout-class) you can read a discussion about view inflating

Answer (score 0):

```
 TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams txtParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        txt.setLayoutParams(txtParams);
        txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt.setText("Hello World");
        txt.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

Use this and you wont see padding anymore!!

Comment: This does not work and it also makes the first `ImageView` in front of the `TextView` have the same height as the parent view not allowing the rest of the views to be displayed.